# Excluding shared dependencies from the assembly of one project

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

In my xml configuration for the `maven-assembly-plugin` of project B, all dependencies of the project are exported to the `lib/` subfolder.

```
<dependencySet>
    <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
    <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
    <outputFileNameMapping>${artifact.artifactId}-${artifact.baseVersion}${dashClassifier?}.${artifact.extension}
    </outputFileNameMapping>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependencySet>
```

However, project B is a plugin for project A, therefore many dependencies are shared and will be already present in project A's assembly.

How do I exclude from B's assembly all of these shared dependencies, please? I saw that there is an [`<excludes>`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_dependencySet) tag, but even if it supports wildcards I'd have to keep the list up to date by hand. Can I exploit the pom files of the two projects somehow instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this issue using scope. in your project B the scope of the common dependency have to be set as provided. That make your dependency (and sub dependency) used only in compile phase. In your pom the dependency shoud looks like:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
            <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

hope this help

Comment: I have a parent pom with dependency management shared among both A and B. Can I set the default scope to `provided` there for the common libs, so that I only have to override it once to `runtime` only in the child's pom of A?

Comment: Apart from the fact that I meant `compile` in my earlier comment, and not `runtime`, it does work. Thanks.